# How use extract php function with ucwords

Tags: php, laravel, function, extract

I would like to know how I can use the php extract function to extract the key from an array to change variables snake_case to camel_case.
Example:

```
array('id' => 1, 'user_name' => 'Paul');
```

To

```
$id = 1;
$userName = 'Paul';
```

I'm using laravel framework.

Thanks;)

Comment: Have you even tried the function you mention? https://3v4l.org/OMqg1

Comment: Also refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274782/convert-array-keys-from-underscore-case-to-camelcase-recursively

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif ... basically, this is quite sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $name = camel_case($key);
    $$name = $value;
}
```

Comment: [You were so preoccupied with whether or not you could you didn't stop to think if you should](http://i.lvme.me/oozm79d.jpg). * - Abraham Lincoln 2014*

Answer (score 0):

You can't with `extract`.

[Quoting the PHP Manua](http://php.net/extract)l (emphasis mine):

> array: An associative array. **This function treats keys as variable names** and values as variable values. For each key/value pair it will create a variable in the current symbol table, subject to flags and prefix parameters.

There is no flag to change the case of the keys. It will use the array key as it appears in the array for the variable name. If you want camel case, you need to change the array key. There is no other way with `extract`.

You could do this in userland with this piece of code:

```
$data = array('id' => 1, 'user_name' => 'Paul');
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    ${lcfirst(str_replace('_', '', ucwords($k, '_')))} = $v;
}
echo $userName;
```

And apparently, [Laravel has a helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-camel-case) for that doing roughly the same under the hood.

But seriously… **don't**. That's very pointless to do.  It's a complete waste of CPU to transform the key to camel case. Just use `$user_name` or `$data['user_name']`.